# Default Content-Type and reading $_POST

Tags: php, post, content-type

Lately I have been facing this issue while reading the data from $_POST.
We have few API's which is been consumed by Mobile apps, and there is a case where the Mobile App is not setting the correct Content-type in header in which case it is being understood as text/plain.
In this particular case, in the php I am not able to read the $_POST data.

The question, aren't we supposed to POST any data when the content-type is text/plain?

I have been searching for this, and did not found any link or reference to it.

Update :

1) The API is being consumed by Mobile APP

2) The request type is already set to POST

Thank you.

Comment: Try this: in the <form ... enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

Comment: Please try to provide piece of code with your question.

Comment: you need to add method they when posting data from client, in your case if you are calling the service you need to provide get/post method.

Comment: @hherger I know adding the enctype will solve the issue. But My question is as what is the relation between POST and content-type ?

Comment: @Mr.Engineer Sorry, but I am only ready $_POST in php as it is mentioned, and the request can be sent from any client.